# What is the AngularJS way to do a client-side include, with route parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Let's say that I have 2 pages in my AngularJS app, one which displays information about an **author**, and another that displays info about a **book**. I have a separate template file, controller, and route for each one. On the author page, I want to display information about the most recent book he's written. How do I do that?

Each of my routes embeds a URL parameter, which tells the controller *which* author or book to fetch data for:

```
.when('/authors/:authorId', { templateUrl: 'author.html', controller: 'AuthorsController')
.when('/books/:bookId', { templateUrl: 'book.html', controller: 'BooksController')
```

As I understand it, I can't use `ng-include` because that doesn't support route parameters, only template files. I could use an **IFrame**, with `src="/books/<bookId>"`, but it feels like there should be an *Angular* way of doing a client-side include with a URL param. I read the [URL Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) wiki page for `ui-router`, but that only covers the *receiving* end of the URL request.

`ng-view` doesn't seem like the right solution either, because I'm already using it in my `index.html` formatting template. Here is the logical structure of the HTML I want to display:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <body>
        <!-- displays template from the current route, e.g. /authors/1 -->
        <div data-ng-view>
            <!-- this HTML is loaded from the author.html template -->
            Author: George R. R. Martin
            (other author details...)

            Most recent book:
            *** THIS IS MY PROBLEM -- HOW TO INCLUDE /books/1 ? ***

                <!-- this HTML is loaded from the book.html template -->
                Title: A Dance with Dragons
                Pub. date: 2011
                ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

To clarify a couple of things:

1. My template files display general information about the author (e.g. name, age) and book (e.g. title, pub. date). They are not specific to a particular author/book, since all of that detail is filled in with data from the server that's been bound to the `$scope`, like `{{ book.title }}`.
2. On the author page, `$scope.latestBookId` contains the ID of the book I want to display. The problem is how to use this ID to `ng-include` my `book.html` template.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
app.controller('AuthorsController', function($scope) {
    var authorId = $routeParams.authorId;

    // these values would be retrieved from the server, using authorId:
    $scope.author = ...;
    $scope.allBooks = [1, 2, ..., 123];
    $scope.mostRecentBookId = 123;
});
```

Snippet from `author.html`:

```
Author: {{author.name}}
Most recent book:
    <!-- all I'm trying to do is to include HTML from a route, but ng-include doesn't support using routes :( -->
    <div ng-include='/books/{{mostRecentBookId}}'></div>


All books:
    <!-- this is where @Akeem's solution breaks down; the knowledge of which bookId to include comes from the HTML below, not the AuthorsController -->
    <div ng-repeat="bookId in allBooks">
        <div ng-include='/books/{{bookId}}'></div>
        <br/>
    </div>
```

**EDIT**
I've applied @Akeem's suggested solution to my example, and added comments about why it won't work for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/o8QbzKqPGjVPcLir80eQ

Comment: from the format i am guessing that you need a book id to show the details of the book and on author's page you dont have any book id am i correct?
so even if you need to show the details of the latest book then your web service which sends you the details of the author must also send you atleast the bookid of the author's latest book

Comment: so your book template files are html specific to each book?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, although ng-include creates a new scope, it also inherits variables from its parent scope.  Therefore, you could set `$scope.bookId` in AuthorsController and perform a check for this variable in BooksController.

```
app.controller('AuthorsController', function($scope) {
  $scope.bookId = 123;
});

app.controller('BooksController', function($scope,$routeParams) {
  if(!$scope.bookId){
    $scope.bookId= $routeParams['bookId'];
  }
  var books = {'1' : 'To Killing a Mockingbird', '23' : 'Harry Potter', '123':'Catch 22'};
  $scope.title = books[$scope.bookId];
});
```

From there, you can combine the ng-include directive with the ng-controller directive to use the BooksController within your author.html template

```
<div ng-include src='"books.html"' ng-controller='BooksController'></div>
```

Finally, in books.html you would reference all variables as normal

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>This is a book with an id of {{bookId}}</p>
<hr>
```

Comment: Ah, you can use shared scope to communicate which `bookId` to display, instead of using a route parameter! This would definitely solve my problem. However, I see 1 problem with it: it introduces a coupling between the `AuthorsController` and `BooksController`. What if I want to show the **two** most recent books on the author's page? Then how will the `BooksController` know which book to display in each case?

Comment: @SteveK In that case you would most likely use ng-repeat with a list of bookIds. From there, you'd have `bookId in bookList` and the same code would apply.

Comment: OK, that would work if I were displaying a simple list of books, because I could assign `bookId` to the individual book in the `ng-repeat` loop. However, what if I want to show the book details for the `mostRecentBookId` first, and then iterate over the rest of the books next? At the point in the source of `author.html` where I'm doing the `ng-include` of `book.html`, the ID of the book to display comes from a different `$scope` variable: `mostRecentBookId` or `bookId` (from the `ng-repeat`). I updated my question to address this use case.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the missing piece, from @Akeem's solution: [`ng-init`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). I've updated my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/o8QbzKqPGjVPcLir80eQ) to use this, and it works. Here is how you ng-include another template, using ng-init to set the `$scope.bookId` variable in lieu of using a route parameter:

```
<div ng-init="bookId = author.mostRecentBook" ng-include="'book.html'"></div>
```

Here is the same thing, but using `ng-repeat` to create the new `$scope.bookId` variable:

```
<li ng-repeat="bookId in author.allBooks" ng-include="'book.html'"/>
```

The downside of doing this is that the calling code is more tightly coupled to the template file it's including, instead of using the route URL as a layer of abstraction. And the controller being called needs to check both the scope *and* route param, to see which is being used to pass in the `bookId`:

```
.controller('BooksController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    if (!$scope.bookId) {
        $scope.bookId = $routeParams['bookId'];
    }
    ...
})
```

My preference is to find a way to include the book data via the route that I have setup (`"/books/:bookId"`), but since there doesn't appear to be a way to do that, some combination of `ng-repeat` and `ng-init` will have to do.

---

Food for thought: maybe angular routes aren't intended to be used to include individual partials, and are only for including a single `ng-view` template per page. But... I bet you could create a directive like:

```
<div ng-include-url="/books/1"></div>
```

which looks up the URL in the `$route` service and does an ng-include using the route's `templateUrl` (and `controller`) property. It would also have to set the `bookId` from the URL in the `$routeParams` object, before it's passed to the controller. I have neither the time nor the AngularJS chops to pull this off, but it just seems useful to use the routes *I already have configured* to dynamically loaded content from one template/controller into another one.